# Selenium and react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, automation

I am trying to write some automation against an application. The application uses `react.js` to render the page. With my browser open I am able to run

```
document.querySelectorAll('a.pointer')[1].click();
```

with no problem. However, once I put it into Selenium web driver - it tells me the `element can't be found`.

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('a.pointer')[1].click();")
```

Any suggestions - I've also tried locating the element by class, CSS selector, and XPath. I added waits to ensure the page was loaded. I simply am not able to interact with the buttons in `react`.

Comment: Did the driver wait for React to complete rendering?

Comment: I believe so - I'm not great at selenium so I had it wait a hard coded 5 and 10 seconds. More than it should take using time.sleep() in python. Is there a better way?

Comment: Paste the exact exception?

Comment: Yea, that whats happens to me as well. 
It seems like an upgrade of React or something major that was changed in React infrastructure. I am trying to dig some more facts and will try to see what can be done.